# Parse a string into a datetime(object) Python

Tags: python, parsing

Some examples:

```
a) Input: “foo document 23rd August 2017” 
Output: datetime(object)
b) Input:“text text 12/09/2014” 
Output: datetime(object)
c) Input: “Bla september 29 of 2014 bla bla”
Output: datetime(object)
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more? E.g. Are you looking for a generic way to extract all these dates? Or separate logic for each type? What have you tried so far? This will help in getting an appropriate answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not be clear

Answer (score 0):

You could try `duckling`  NLP library to parse your unstructured text to identify the datetime. [check document](https://duckling.wit.ai/)

You can install `duckling` using `docker`. Please find the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rasa/duckling)

**Duckling Supports:**

1. time
2. email
3. number
4. url
5. phone-number

and many other formats. It can extract various formats of time e.g: “today”
“Monday, Feb 18”
“the 1st of march”
“last week”
“a quarter to noon”

**How to start `duckling` library:**

Duckling image runs on `8000/tcp` port. It is a `restful` service. Once you installed docker, you can start the duckling image as follows:

```
docker container run <duckling-container-image-id> -p 8000:8000
```

Then, you can check the `localhost:8000` it responds with text `quack` output.

**How to access duckling rest service in `python`:**

```
import requests, json
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/parse", data={"text":"Bla september 29 of 2014 bla bla","locale":"en_GB"})
## response status code 200 then,
if response:
    print(json.loads(response.text))
```

**output:**

```
[{'body': 'september 29 of 2014', 'start': 4, 'value': {'values': [{'value': '2014-09-29T00:00:00.000-07:00', 'grain': 'day', 'type': 'value'}], 'value': '2014-09-29T00:00:00.000-07:00', 'grain': 'day', 'type': 'value'}, 'end': 24, 'dim': 'time', 'latent': False}]
```